# Commands argmin and argmax in algorithm

Tags: macros, algorithms

I am trying to use the `argmin` and the `argmax` commands that I defined in an algorithm but I keep getting the argument not in the middle but on the right. Does anyone have an idea how to put the argument in the middle.

I declare the operators:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
```

and I use the following packages to write algorithms:

```
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

Full algorithm code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE some statement here
\WHILE{!stop}
    \STATE $s_{i} = \argmin_{p} \| l_{j} - s_{p} \|$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: i don't understand why you use the already-defined `\arg` and `\min` rather than just `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$` introduces text style, you will need either `\displaystyle`  or `\limits`.
(`\sum`, `\int`, `\lim`, … behave in the same manner: Display-style formulas have their super- and subscripts above and below the sign, in text-style formulas they are typeset like normal super- and subscripts.)

If you find both solutions unsatisfying you can define an additional command that has `\limits`built in:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\newcommand*{\argminl}{\argmin\limits}
\newcommand*{\argmaxl}{\argmax\limits}
```

or with your original macro names having that feature:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminOp}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmaxOp}{argmax}
\newcommand*{\argmin}{\argminOp\limits}
\newcommand*{\argmax}{\argmaxOp\limits}
```

But than you could just make it without `\DeclareMathOperator*`:

```
\newcommand*{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}\limits}
\newcommand*{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}\limits}
```

*I have also declared your operators with out the predefined operators `\arg` and `\max` as operators are usually in upright font anyway, and then there's no need to re-adjust the space manually (the `\!`).*

### Code A (`\limits`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE some statement here
\WHILE{!stop}
    \STATE $s_{i} = \argmin\limits_{p} \| l_{j} - s_{p} \|$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

### Code B (`\displaystyle`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE some statement here
\WHILE{!stop}
    \STATE $\displaystyle s_{i} = \argmin_{p} \| l_{j} - s_{p} \|$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

### Code C (built in `\limits`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\newcommand*{\argminl}{\argmin\limits}
\newcommand*{\argmaxl}{\argmax\limits}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE some statement here
\WHILE{!stop}
    \STATE $ s_{i} = \argminl_{p} \| l_{j} - s_{p} \|$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\limits` (but this will disrupt the regular skip between consecutive lines):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE some statement here
\WHILE{!stop}
    \STATE $s_{i} = \argmin\limits_{p} \| l_{j} - s_{p} \|$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]