# writing an algorithm in a table

Tags: algorithms

I want to write an algorithm in a table for my paper. I tried to write it, but I want to write ''While'' instead of ''for'' in this algorithm. How can I do it? And I want to put the table everywhere in the text.

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{
OMP Algorithm
    }
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{latin}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE Decomposition of signal ‎$x‎$‎
            \STATE\textbf{Input:}  signal ‎$‎x \in \mathcal{R}^{m}‎$‎, Dictionary ‎$‎‎\mathcal{G}‎ ‎\in ‎\mathcal{R}^{m \times n‎‎}‎$‎,‎‎$‎\hat{x}=‎\emptyset‎$‎ ‎‎
            \STATE  \textbf{Output:}  Decomposed signal $‎\hat{x}_{est}‎‎$ ‎after ‎$‎k‎$‎ ‎‎iteration, Residual ‎‎$‎R^{(k)}‎$‎‎
      \STATE ‎\textbf{Initialization} ‎$‎‎R^{(0)}=x‎‎$‎
            \STATE \textbf{for i=1:k do}‎
            \STATE ‎$‎l‎=\displaystyle{arg\max_{l=1,\dots ,l} |‎\langle ‎g_l,R^{(i)} ‎‎\rangle‎‎|‎}$‎‎‎ ‎\qquad‎ ‎finding ‎the ‎atom ‎in ‎dictionary ‎‎$‎\mathcal{G}‎$‎ ‎‎with ‎maximum ‎correlation ‎with ‎residual.‎
            \STATE ‎$‎R^{(i+1)}=R{(i)}-a_l g_l^{(i)}‎‎$‎
            \STATE ‎$\hat{x}‎=‎\hat{x}‎+‎\langle ‎R^{(i)},g_{l}^{(i)} ‎‎\rangle ‎g_{l}^{(i)}‎‎$‎
      \STATE \‏‎textbf{end}‎
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{latin}
\end{‎algorithm}
```

[image: algorithm]

Comment: Related, or possibly duplicate: [do-while loop in pseudo code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115709/do-while-loop-in-pseudo-code) -- question shows a while loop. Also, section 3.1.2 of [algorithmicx documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

There are more tools at your disposal inside the `algorithmic` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible,amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83169/5764
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\textbf{Input:}]}%
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\textbf{Output:}]}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{OMP Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE Decomposition of signal $x$
    \INPUT signal $x \in \mathcal{R}^{m}$, Dictionary $\mathcal{G} \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n‎‎}$, $\hat{x} = \emptyset$
    \OUTPUT Decomposed signal $\hat{x}_{\text{est}}$ after $k$ iteration, Residual $R^{(k)}$
    \STATE \textbf{Initialization} ‎$R^{(0)} = x$
    \WHILE{$i \leq k$}
      \STATE $l = \displaystyle \argmax_{l = 1,\dots,l} |\langle g_l,R^{(i)} \rangle|$
        \COMMENT{finding the atom in dictionary $\mathcal{G}$ ‎with maximum correlation with residual.}
      \STATE $R^{(i+1)} = R{(i)}-a_l g_l^{(i)}‎$
      \STATE $\hat{x} = \hat{x}+\langle R^{(i)}, g_{l}^{(i)} \rangle g_{l}^{(i)}‎$
      \STATE $i = i + 1$
    \ENDWHILE
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

`algcompatible` (from [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) provides `\WHILE{<condition>}` and `\ENDWHILE`. As you can see, it also indents the statement to show it's (nested) structure.

For completeness, I've also defined `\INPUT` and `\OUTPUT`, similar to the existence of `\REQUIRE` and `\ENSURE`.

If you want to write this *outside* of the `algorithm` float, then you only need to use the `algorithmic` environment content. If you wish to also add a caption, then I suggest you use `\begin{algorithm}[H]` ...`\end{algorithm}` instead ([`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) uses [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) to define the `algorithm` environment, and therefore supports the ["HERE" float specification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)).