# Citations no longer worker

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I was able to previously cite my work in LaTeX, but unfortunately it no longer works.

Here are the packages I'm loading at the beginning of my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno,tikz]{amsart}
\makeatletter
\let\NAT@parse\undefined
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,algorithm,algcompatible}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{1.4}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{−}{-}     

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83169/5764
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\textbf{Input:}]}%
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\textbf{Output:}]}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand\MyBox[2]{
  \fbox{\lower0.75cm
    \vbox to 1.7cm{\vfil
      \hbox to 1.7cm{\hfil\parbox{1.4cm}{#1\\#2}\hfil}
      \vfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
```

Unfortunately the citations appear in the following manner:

```
{citation}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you press the button to start the program that takes care of the bibliography?

Comment: You are showing many irrelevant parts as the page style but no relevant parts as a minimal biblio.bib file and how you cite it at least once. And It is not understandable what mean `{citation}` (maybe the bibkey in bold in the PDF?)